# creating structure and getting data in Firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to Firestore & Firebase. I am from Sql Background and I am planning to create new `IONIC,Angular` application. I have decided to use either `firebase or firestore` but I feel `firestore` has some limitation in fetching queries if I think from SQL background. Let me come to my requirement. It is simple in terms of SQL.

I have a `user` table

```
user -> UID,FirstName,LastName,Age,DateCreated,Status,Email
```

I have another table as `Products`

```
Products -> PID, ProductName,ProductDescriptio,Price,UID
```

if you notice Products table you can understand UID is a key from User table. This is how it is defined in SQL.

Here I can find all the products which is related to User and also I can apply filters such as date & email to get specific products.

I understand `filestore is a collection ->document ->Collection ->document` style structure.

How can I create these structure and query in firestore using Angular. IS this poosible in firestore / firebase or should go back to Sql again.

Thanks

Comment: @Hareesh Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

In your case you have a 1 to many relationship. This allows your user document to have a collection of products. Retrieving the collection of product for a specific user is easy:

`db.collection('users').doc(userId).collection('products')`

These can then be filtered using firestore queries. Note that these filters are very limited compared to SQL. Read the [guides of firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/) to learn more about the limits.

In firestore there is no concept of many-to-many relations, they would have to be modeled manually. For retrieving data you would have to loop through on end of the relation and fetch the other end in that loop. This is a no-no in SQL land, but in most cases fine with Firestore because of the websocket connection.

In any case, most of the filtering can be modelled, either by smartly using queries or by denormalizing data. This however requires a totally different mindset than the SQL mindset.

If you need to do complex filtering, full text search or aggregation firebase is not the product to provide that. We usually use firebase to store the data, then listen for changes, index into elasticsearch and use that to query the data.

What advise to give really depends on your specific use case. Knowing the exact limitations and experimenting with different scenario's is essential.